# 6v switching large load

Tags: transistors, switches, relay

I'm looking to build a remote firework launcher. I'm using parts from an rc car for the remote, but I need a circuit that can switch a large current (~2-3amps) with 6v. Can I do this with a transistor, or will I need to buy a voltage relay?

Comment: Why can't you just use a switch? That is, no transistor, no relay, just a switch.

Comment: I'm trying to make it remote using the rf controller for my rc car.

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET may* be more suitable - Particularly if your available drive current is limited. The current required to drive the gate is almost zero.

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=ATP202  Is an example of a device with suitable Vth and RdsON, it will happily switch 3A with little to no heat-sinking. Note it is only 30V maximum, generally suitable for switching < 24V at the output.

*I would recommend adding a 'free-wheel diode' for inductive loads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use darlington transistors like TIP122, these can work out on loads around 10A with a little base current, you only need a transistor in each of your loads (if it's going to be asynchronous, otherwise you could pair them on parallel) and add a resistor at the base that can manage your base current depending on your trigger voltage. If you need help in the calculation of the resistor let us see a schematic of your design. Hope this helps you

Comment: Even if you use relays you would need transistors to trigger these on.